# What does the bokeh decorator @without_document_lock() mean?

Tags: python, tornado, bokeh

The [bokeh server documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) includes an example of *updating from unlocked callbacks.* It states:

> Normally Bokeh session callbacks recursively lock the document until all future work they initiate is complete. However, you may want to drive blocking computations from callbacks using Tornado’s ThreadPoolExecutor in an asynchronous callback. This can work, but requires the Bokeh provided without_document_lock() decorator to suppress the normal locking behavior.

What does this mean?  Does it mean, for example, that without the decorator, then once invoked, a callback and anything it calls runs to completion before surrendering control back to the main IOLoop?

Whereas with the decorator, the main event loop continues while the callback executes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does this mean? Does it mean, for example, that without the decorator, then once invoked, a callback and anything it calls runs to completion before surrendering control back to the main IOLoop?

It means no other Bokeh callbacks will even start to execute while another one is in-flight with a lock on the `Document`, regardless of whether they are on different threads.

But you can override that, e.g. if you have a callback on a thread that does an expensive "non-Bokeh" computation, then updates a few Bokeh properties at the end. You can decorate that callback 
 to be `@without_document_lock()` so it can always start and do the expensive "non-Bokeh work" in the background, regardless of any other Bokeh callbacks that might be executing. You just have to follow the pattern in the link and put any actual Bokeh property updates in a "next tick" callback (all actual updates to Bokeh models have to occur in callbacks that have a Document lock, like a next tick callback)

Comment: Thanks.  I am going to ask a related question about this example.